# Opening a folder through FireFox with HTML

Tags: html, firefox, window.open

I recently built a HTML and Javascript web application that opens specific folders throughout a network of accessible drives.  This app works well when it is rendered in IE; however, the folder paths do not work in FireFox.

The following is an example of the path format that I am using to open the folders in IE:

```
{
    window.open('\\\\Server-1\\Folder-1\\Folder-2');
}
```

***The path actually has 4 backward slashes at the beginning and 2 bakcward slashes between each folder.  It appears different when rendered.***

When I run this app in FireFox, the window or new tab appears, but there is nothing rendered.  I've manually entered the path and FireFox converts it to: `file://///Server-1/Folder-1/Folder-2`.  Does anyone know what the correct syntax would be (i.e. `window.open(?...)`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that might help you. It is considered a security risk by Mozilla.

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_do_not_work

Comment: Thanks Daniel - After reviewing the article, I fouhnd the correct syntax to be file://///Server-1/Folder-1/Folder-1.  What is interesting is that this also works in IE so I do not have to write if statements.

Thanks again,

DFM

Answer (score 1):

according to [Daniel's link](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_do_not_work) you need THREE forward slashes not FOUR for local paths...

> Path Syntax
>
> You also need to use proper URI syntax
>   for local file references. It is not
>   proper to enter an
>   operating-system-specific path, such
>   as c:\subdir\file.ext without
>   converting it to a URI, which in this
>   case would be
>   **file:///c:/subdir/file.ext**. In
>   general, a file path is converted to a
>   URI by adding the scheme identifier
>   file:, then three forward slashes
>   (representing an empty authority or
>   host segment), then the path with all
>   backslashes converted to forward
>   slashes.

Comment: Thanks Pageman - I actual found the correct syntax from the artical, which requires 5 slashes at the beginning and 1 per folder.

Thank you,

DFM

Comment: @DFM who would have thought? you needed one more slash! :) or rather, two! :)